# How to extract archive or change permissions when there are "read-only file system" errors?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, archive, read-only, unzip

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and having a problem changing the file permission of a `.zip` file. I can neither extract it nor change file permissions. When I extract it by command

```
unzip Ex_Files_JS_EssT_2011.zip
```

it shows me the following error:

```
checkdir error:  cannot create Ex_Files_JS_EssT_2011
read-only file system
unable to process Ex_Files_JS_EssT_2011
```

When I'm execute the command `sudo chmod 777 Ex_Files_JS_EssT_2011.zip` it gives me the following error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of ‘Ex_Files_JS_EssT_2011.zip’: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is on a read-only filesystem. This may be a disk that cannot be written to (such as most CDs). Or it may be on a disk that can be written to, mounted to allow reading only.

With more information about where the file is located, you might be able to remount the filesystem read-write. But if not, or if you don't want to bother with that (which you probably don't), there is a generic solution. Simply **copy the archive to some location that you can write to**. Then you can extract it.

You can do this in Nautilus (the graphical file browser). You can even extract the archive graphically, if you wish (either by double-clicking on its icon, or by right-clicking on its icon and clicking one of the *Extract* options).

Or if you want to use the command line, you can do:

```
cp Ex_Files_JS_EssT_2011.zip ~/Desktop
cd ~/Desktop
unzip Ex_Files_JS_EssT_2011.zip
```

That example copies it to your desktop and extracts it there. You might prefer to instead copy it to your home folder (which your desktop exists as a subfolder of), by replacing `~/Desktop` with `~/`, or perhaps to the global temporary folder `/tmp` by replacing `~/Desktop` with that.